# iOS - How to inject data to view controller displayed within tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, uitabbarcontroller

I've got an iOS app that has a page view to show multiple items as pages. Each page contains a tab bar controller with 2 tabs so I can show the info for each page in 2 ways - as a table or as a graph. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Pages and tabs screenshot]

So the user chooses which item to look at (in this case bananas) by changing pages. But I can't figure out where or how I should inject which item they're looking at into the 2 view controllers within the tab controller. Here's a shot of my storyboard if that helps. I want to inject it when the table view controller or graph controller are created but I can't see where that's happening to get at that code - have I missed something?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work the same in the storybaord environment, but there is UITabBarControllerDelegate that has a callback method named didSelectViewController.  It will give you the viewcontroller that is being selected.  [Doc from Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate)

Comment: Tried this too - made my tab bar controller subclass implement UITabBarControllerDelegate and set it as the tab bar delegate but on running it I get the following error: 'Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: Got a variant of this working - I'm no longer setting up the UITabBarController in the storyboard, but creating a new one programatically when the view it's displayed in is loaded. I then set its delegate as you've said and can use the didSelectViewController: method. It also means I manually create the table and graph controllers so I can inject stuff to them at creation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you should subclass your tab bar controller and implement the

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

method.

In there you can access the destination view controller by the segue object's destinationViewController property.

Depending on the segue identifier you can customise your destination view controller:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueID"]) {
    MyViewController *myViewController = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    //customize view controller
}
```

Comment: I've just tried this but the prepareForSegue: method is never called - the lines between the tab bar controller and the table/graph controllers are 'relationships' not segues - there's nowhere to set a segue identifier either.